# Passing variables when invoking a Python script

Tags: python, variables

Is it possible to pass variables to Python when invoking a script from a bash shell?

For example, when I would call my_script in the shell like this:

```
python my_script.py -par1 -par2
```

is it possible to use `par1` and `par2` as variables in Python so I can pass them as arguments to a function?

Something similar like for shell scripting, where in something like this:

```
my_script.sh par1
```

`par1` would be stored as $1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell:

```
python my_script.py -par1 -par2
```

Python:
Passing them as arguments to a function:

```
import sys

arg1,arg2 = sys.argv[1:3]

myfunc(arg1,arg2)
```

Comment: Just to add that `sys.argv[0]` is the filename and `sys.argv[1]` is the first argument and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the commandline arguments from [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

Python also comes with a variety of commandline processing utilities.  I would recommend [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) which is included in the standard library starting with version 2.7.  But there is also `optparse` or even `getopt` for the adventurous.